# Why all my discrod.net bots stopped working?

Tags: .net, discord, discord.net

idk why, but all my discord.net bots modules stopped working. I tried to restart my PC and use old git branches. There is no error or message. In HandleCommandAsync don't go after "if", but it has to go.[image]

```
public class CommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly CommandService _commands;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CommandHandler(DiscordSocketClient client, CommandService commands, IServiceProvider services, ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _client = client;
        _commands = commands;
        _services = services;
    }

    public async Task InstallCommandsAsync()
    {
        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
        
        await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), 
            _services);
    }

    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage message)
    {
        if (message is not SocketUserMessage userMessage) return;

        int argPos = 0;

        _logger.LogDebug("start Handle");
        _logger.LogDebug($"userMessage.HasCharPrefix: {!userMessage.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos)}");
        _logger.LogDebug($"userMessage.HasMentionPrefix: {userMessage.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos)}");

        if (!(userMessage.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos) || 
              userMessage.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos)) ||
            userMessage.Author.IsBot)
            return;

        _logger.LogDebug("Handle");
        
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, userMessage);

        await _commands.ExecuteAsync(
            context: context, 
            argPos: argPos, 
            services: _services);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, [not screenshots](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @DourHighArch like that?

Comment: Yes. If “don't go after "if"” means ”Handle” is never written, then I suspect your second `if` statement is true and you call `return`. Try logging `userMessage`.

Comment: @DourHighArch I just woke up, turn on my pc, and seems like everything work again, now I don't understand at all...